# Does the way of instantiating a new Thread make a difference?

Tags: java, instantiation, java-threads

What are the difference (if any) between instantiating a *Thread* like this

```
SomeThread t = new SomeThread();
t.start();
```

and like this:

```
new SomeThread().start();
```

Will the *constructor* in *class SomeThread* still be instantiated?

Or does it actually skip instantiating the constructor the second time and go straight for the *run()-* method?

Note: The class *SomeThread* extends Thread

Comment: How would it skip the constructor? You're still *calling* the constructor... you're just not saving the value in a variable.

Comment: no much difference.. .if you use the second way to create a thread and call it.. you wont be able to call any other method on that thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new keyword is used for object creation, and you are still calling the constructor, as you can see with the call to **SomeThread()**. The two code examples above are equivalent.

Comment: yes, they do the same work, but it's hard to say that these snippets are equivalent

Comment: I'd argue that as the t variable is unused in the first example, these two pieces of code are equivalent, they do the exact same thing. In the wider context of a program, yes they are not equivalent as the variable t would likely be named better and reused later in the program.

Comment: Couldn't edit the previous message, but rather than equivalent, I'd say it's functionally equivalent

Answer (score 3):

> Or does it actually skip instantiating the constructor the second time...?

The constructor gets called and the instance is initialized in both cases. The difference is the inability of reuse the instance created in the second example.

To make them equivalent, you need to save that instance into a variable:

```
SomeThread t;
(t = new SomeThread()).start();
```

> ... and go straight for the `run()` method?

The `run` method is an instance method, therefore to call it you have to invoke this method on an already defined object.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference except that the first case keeps a reference to the variable. The constructor always runs when you create an instance.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods call the constructor and instantiate the object. The difference is simply that you skip variable assignment of the instantiated object in the second case.

You can easily test that on your own by letting the constructor have some side effect like printing to std out (e.g. below prints two times called).

```
package com.example;


public final class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeThread thread1 = new SomeThread();
        thread1.run();

        new SomeThread().run();
    }


    public static final class SomeThread extends Thread{


        public SomeThread() {
            System.out.println("called");
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
        }
    }
}
```

When you do not work with the variable in your code, there is no real difference between both methods.

Comment: Agree, I could've made a test--it just didn't come to mind